# c++ string concatenation second time

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-concatenation, stringstream

I am a newbie, writing a c++ code to open and read from multiple files and then dump part of the data into other files.
I want to generate file names in a for loop. 
But I can't concatenate string(numbering of file) and string literal(a file extension). The same line of code works at the very beginning of the program, but not at the later part.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << std::string("9") + ".dat" << std::endl;

    // many more lines

    dump = 1;
    if (dump == 1){
        for (int ilevel=std::max(levelmin,lmin); ilevel < lmax + 1; ilevel++){
            std::cout << std::string("9") + ".dat" << std::endl; // crashes here!
            std::ofstream fout (std::string("9") + ".dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            std::cout << grid[ilevel].cube[0] << std::endl;

            fout.write ((char*)&grid[ilevel].cube[0], grid[ilevel].cube.size() * sizeof(grid[ilevel].cube[0]));
            fout.close();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If I put `std::cout << std::string("9") + ".dat" << std::endl;` at the beginning, it works and prints "9.dat".
but in the later loop, segmentation fault.

In between I call a function that uses stringstream to pad leading zeros to an integer. The function looks:

```
std::string int2str(const int n, const int m){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(m) << n;
    std::string s2(ss.str());
    ss.clear();
    return s2;
}
```

I don't have a clear understanding about string and stringstream in c++.
But out of many things in my program, this function is the only thing I can think of being relevant. Other parts of codes does not deal with strings. It's mostly array manipulation code.

I've also tried `std::string("9") + std::string(".dat")`
but had no luck.
What is wrong?

Comment: Calling `ss.clear()` on a variable that is about to go out of scope and run its destructor is pointless. Similarly for `f.close()`, it's about to run its destructor anyway. The destructor closes the file.

Comment: If it really crashes where you say it does, it's almost certainly caused by memory corruption. Can you please isolate an actual [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your code and post it? That is, something *minimal* we could copy & paste to e.g. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and see the error ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you're using `std::string("9")` rather than just `"9"`?

Where does the `9` come from? If its generated as part of a loop or a returned value from a function you can either place the variable itself to be concatenated, or the function that returns it, so:

`std::cout << iFileNumber + ".dat" << std::endl;`

or

`std::cout << fileNumberGenerator() + ".dat" << std::endl;`

For the hardcoded examples you've provided, I personally can't see the need for anything other than

`std::cout << 9 + ".dat" << endl;`

but that could easily just be lack of experience on my part.

For the sake of printing to the command line, its also worth nothing that this is equally acceptable syntax (assuming you're not already aware):

`std::cout << 9 << ".dat" << endl;`